# @EJB dependency Injection doesn't work in JBoss AS 6 NullPointerException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, cdi

```
public interface ModelClient {
    public JSONObject _callModel(URL url);
}

@Stateless
@Local(ModelClient.class)
public class ModelClientBean implements ModelClient {
    public JSONObject _callModel(URL url) { /* some implementation */ }
}

@Stateless(name="ejb/ModelServiceBean")
public class ModelServiceBean {

   @EJB
   private ModelClient modelClient;
}
```

JBoss AS 6 says:

```
17:25:30,186 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=rms-ear.ear,jar=rms-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=ModelClientBean,service=EJB3
17:25:30,187 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.domain.rms.ejbs.ModelClientBean ejbName: ModelClientBean
17:25:30,250 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.jndiregistrar.JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:
rms-ear/rms-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/ModelClientBean!local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
rms-ear/rms-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/ModelClientBean!com.domain.rms.ejbs.ModelClient - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

so far so good.
But any attempt to modelClient results with "NullPointerException".

Any Idea ?

UPDATE: ModelServiceBean is looked up over JNDI (InitialContext) from a non-managed context

```
public JobServiceCall() {
    Context context = null;
    try {
        context = new InitialContext();
        modelServiceBean = (ModelServiceBean)context.lookup("..");
    } catch ()...
 }
```

The exception stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.domain.rms.ejbs.ModelClientBean._callModel(ModelClientBean.java:53) [:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_24]
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:72) [:1.1.3]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:76) [:1.1.3]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:62) [:1.1.3]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor279.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_24]
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:74) [:1.1.3]
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_11016588.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_11016588.java)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:90) [:1.1.3]
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_11016588.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_11016588.java)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.async.impl.interceptor.AsynchronousServerInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousServerInterceptor.java:128) [:1.7.17]
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62) [:1.7.17]
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56) [:1.7.17]
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47) [:1.7.17]
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42) [:1.0.3]
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68) [:1.7.17]
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.SessionInvocationContextAdapter.proceed(SessionInvocationContextAdapter.java:95) [:1.7.17]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:223) [:0.0.1]
    ... 109 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you get hold to an instance of ModelServiceBean? Injection only works when ModelServiceBean itself is injected into some managed bean (e.g. a Servlet, JSF Managed bean, etc) or when you request it via JNDI.

Injection will not happen when you instantiate the class with the new operator.

Comment: ModelServiceBean is looked up over JNDI (InitialContext) from a non-managed context.

Comment: Where do you see this NPE? Inside ModelClientBean? Maybe you should post the stack trace.

Comment: As I expected, the injection of a ModelClient instance happened just fine. It's not the injected reference that is null, but the problem is simply within the `_callModel` method that. Somewhere in the part that you left out with `/* some implementation */` (at line 53) your code causes a NPE to be thrown.

Comment: i found it. /* some implementation */ (at line 53) reads from InputStream and creates a json object. i get at this point an exception, can not read from InputStream etc. thank you very much for your support

Answer (score 0):

We use @LocalBean rather than @Local on the implementation. I also see @Local on interfaces that are not remote.

Just a guess but I think that this might work:

```
@Local
public interface ModelClient {
    public JSONObject _callModel(URL url);
}

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ModelClientBean implements ModelClient {
    public JSONObject _callModel(URL url) { /* some implementation */ }
}
```

Comment: @LocalBean isn't needed here, this only defines an additional no-interface view which OP isn't using. Putting @Local on the interface is recommended, but using @Local on the bean class with a reference to the interface has the same effect. It just directly enforces the contract between bean and the interface, which is generally seen as not optimal.